# Troubleshooting UPS failure

Tags: ups, troubleshooting

My wife said her office had an old UPS that was being scraped because it wasn't working.  I picked it up and plugged it in and nothing happened.  No lights, no warnings, nothing.

It's a small guy.**[EDIT: APC Smart-UPS 700]**  Holds two 12V 7.2Ah batteries in series.  I checked the batteries with a volt meter and each of them are sitting at 2.7-3Volts each.  Okay, really dead batteries.  I hooked the battery connectors to my DMM and plugged it in again to check for voltage.  I got a quick spike up to around 8 volts when I first plugged it in but then the voltage just bled away...assuming a cap discharging (?).

I guess my question is this.  If there are no batteries connected to a typical UPS (it's like an APS brand UPS) will it just sit there and act dead?  What is the usual way a UPS goes about doing its job of providing power while collecting some for a rainy day?

I don't really want to go out and buy new batteries for this unit if I haven't confirmed it works.

What can I check before I start ripping the thing apart for connectors and inductors?

Comment: Usually UPS are scraped from professional environment every 3-4 years. It may be due to bad /depleted SLA or the bad logic circuitry. Due to high labor costs in developed countries, the cost of replacing them is lower than cost of repairing them. I personally don't agree to send them to landfill.

Comment: I would start by checking the obvious, plug, wire, switches, fuse, etc. Try an auto battery, to see if the output works.

Comment: See if you can charge/resuscitate the batteries on the bench.  If they hold any sort of a charge (they really don't need to hold up under load), you can re-test the UPS with them.

Comment: They usually do not work when the batteries are really bad as in your case. If its a new(say 2003+ ?) APC one the holding in the on button for several seconds should turn it on if the only problem is the batteries.

Answer (score 1):

It very well may, be that this particular unit is "advanced enough," to just not do anything once it senses that the batteries are beyond dead! There are many other problems, but dead batteries are *almost* always the problem!

> I don't really want to go out and buy new batteries for this unit if I
>   haven't confirmed it works.

I have repaired a good deal of these types of units. The next most likely problem is that the "voltage sensing circuitry" is either bad, or is not designed to work with the power (voltage, frequency, etc.) that you are supplying it while you're trying to test it.

> What can I check before I start ripping the thing apart for connectors
>   and inductors?

So these are the two main things to start with. However you should first research exactly what model it is, etc. (And post it back here so we can better help you!)

Comment: I added model to question...APC Smart-UPS 700

Comment: @ChefFlambe I'll look it up when I have a second. Not sure if anyone has suggested this... But you may want to check if there are any fuses, and verify AC is getting to the PCB, because people aren't too gentle when removing these units sometimes.

Comment: Haven't checked for any internal fuses yet, would mean total disassemble.  There's a reset fuse button on the back that appears okay.  I know sometimes the step dowm transformer can die and you usually see an open when checking across the power plug leads but that was okay.